# Sending a file to the browser for Downloading

Tags: javascript, linux, perl

I am building a simple visual downloader. Users select the files they want to download and then download those files. However the files that I am dealing with are rather large. What I have done is let users select the files they need and passed the list of filenames to perl sucessfully. What I want to do is to stream a compressed tarball to their browser via a perl script but I'm not sure as to how I would that.

If I run a system command to tar a whole bunch of files (the names of which are in an array) how would I "stream" the tarball directly so that the user can download the files without storing the compressed tarball locally?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

EDIT: So I have perl streaming the file but how do I handle it at the Javascript end.

The perl call is being made like this:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cgi-bin/download.pl",
        data: info,
        success: function(data){
            window.open(data,'Download');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a pipe.

Run tar without an f argument (i.e. no file, output to standout out). Then capture and send the output. You can use `popen()`, or just backticks: `.

Comment: Thanks. But how do I handle the reply from the perl script in javascript? Javascript calls the perl function via an ajax call.

Comment: Don't use ajax. Just `document.location` to the perl page. And to answer your question on the other reply, you put the list of files in the url for `document.location`. Example: `document.location=download.perl?file1=foo&file2=bar` etc. Or use an array in the url parameters. `$.param()` can help you with this.

Comment: I got everything working thanks :). But just one more thing, will it only let the user download once it has finished creating the tarball? Is there a way to pipe it to download while compressing and creating? Currently:

print "Content-Type:application/x-download\n"; 
print "Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=download.tar.gz\n\n";
print `tar zc - $path/$file`

Comment: @Falcata That looks fine to me except there is no such thing as `application/x-download` use `application/octet-stream` or `application/x-tar`. It should allow download while creating the tar, if not you will need to investigate buffering, and find out who is buffering it.

Answer (score 1):

- Generate the output file
- Send out the MIME header
- Stream the file
- See: http://forums.devshed.com/beginner-programming-16/perl-script-for-force-download-i-know-it-s-been-asked-128474.html for example

Comment: I am doing the exact same thing! But how do I hand it on the JavaScript end?

Comment: Don't use AJAX, just make a URL GET/POST call from the page. The MIME header will automatically open the download dialog.

Comment: If I don't use ajax then I can't pass in the list of files that I nee to download.